# Cannot create file anywhere on drive C:

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I just did a clean install of Windows 10 Pro. For some reason I am missing the "New > File" context entries when I am opening the right click context menu anywhere on drive C: that is not my user folder (`C:\Program Files` for example). All I can see is the option to create a folder:

[image: missing new file entry]

I am on an Admin account (the only Account on the system) and haven't installed any programs yet. I can copy files to any folder without problem and also create folders as much as I like, but there is no option to create files.

In the example above I am even in a folder I create myself. Owner of the folder is the Administrators group, which I am a member of and which has full write rights.

The context entry appears when I am in my "Documents" folder and on different drives, but not on most folders in C:

What is going on? How can I create files anywhere on C:?

Comment: Did you try to run cmd and run `md dirname` inside?

Answer (score 4):

I've formatted my laptop yesterday (reinstalled W10), and today (an hour ago) I've noticed this problem. I cannot create a file in C. I can create/delete a folder, but not file. I can create the file elsewhere and move it to C, but then I can't delete the file. I don't remember having this problem before. (Maybe I did, and got around it, but I don't remember it.)

I've formatted two laptops and both laptops had the same problem. I've experimented with the permissions and owners, but nothing worked. I was so furious. Then I decided to reformat.

Now I have a clean Windows 10. I right click in C and all I can see in "New" submenu is just "Folder". Then I change the permissions: `(C:) Properties -> Security -> Group or user names -> Edit -> Users -> Full control`. Now I can see the full list in "New" submenu, although I still can't create a file. When I click on "Text Document", I get the following error:

> An unexpected error is keeping you from creating the file. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
>
> Error 0x80070522: A required privilage is not held by the client.

When I searched for a solution on the internet, people suggested that UAC should be turned off. So I turned it off: `Control Panel -> System and Security -> Security and Maintenance -> Change User Account Control settings -> Never notify`. But this didn't do any good. So I looked again. Some suggested that it should be turned off in the registry. So I run the following registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLUA"=dword:00000000
```

This change requires a restart. After I restarted, I could create files in C.

I'm writing this answer from another laptop (the second one) with the same problem. Though this Windows is not so clean. I've played a little with the ownership and permissions, and installed/updated things. The above registry also worked on this one.

Normally I'd edit the ownership and permissions to get access to folders/files in C, but just giving full access to Users and the above registry change seem to work fine for now. Now, I've gotta complete the installations on the first one.

I'll be updating this answer if I come across this error (or something related to it) again.

Comment: This is just perfect, thank you. I wish I could downvote the answer: https://superuser.com/a/1062737/691556

Comment: Changing the "EnableLUA" registry key to 0 worked for me as well on Windows 10 as of October 2022, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

If UAC is enabled, even if you are part of the administrator's group, you are by default logged in as a standard user. A standard user cannot create a file on C:\ . Hence you do not get an option to create one.

If you create a new folder on C:\, you will be its owner and hence you can create files in it and Windows 10 will show you options in the new menu to create them.

You can create a file on your desktop and move it to C:\ . Windows will prompt you to elevate and do the needful elevation transparently.

Comment: Apparently not, I created the "Syncthing" folder shown in the screenshot manually and still don't get the option inside. Anyway, is there any solution to change this? I have no problem with UAC double checking, but not being able at all to create a file seems very limited.

Comment: Can you check the Security tab of Syncthing folder and check if your user acount has full control?

Comment: Also, since you elevated to create the folder, it was created with your administrative token. If you manuallya add your account to the folder's security, you will be able to add new files. Explorer runs as a standard user.

Comment: "Program Files" is a protected folder, and any subfolders created will also be protected, unless the permissions are specifically changed. Moving (but not copying) a subfolder with more liberal permission entries to Program Files will retain those permissions.

Answer (score -2):

Ransomware protection in Windows 10 OFF did the trick for me.